# How to compare multiple values in an if statement at once in Dart

Tags: dart

I have multiple variables which needs the same check in a if-statement in Dart. I need to know if there is at least one of the variables > 0.

For example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;

if ((a > 0) || (b > 0) || (c > 0)) {
  print('Yeh!');
}
```

This should be done easier, like in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value).

The following code isn't valid, but I tried this:

```
if ((a || b || c) > 0) {
  print('Yeh!');
}
```

Any tips would be nice.

Comment: Even in Python, `(a or b or c) > 0` works only in *that particular case*.  It wouldn't work if your comparison were, say, `> 1`, or if `a` were `-1`.  IMO `(a or b or c) > 0` would be dangerously misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to create a `List` and to use [`Iterable.any`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/any.html):

```dart
if ([a, b, c].any((x) => x > 0)) {
  print('Yeh!');
}
```

Comment: Has this answer disadvantages over doing it like OP did first e. g. is it way slower?

Comment: @kk_ I'd expect it to be slightly slower since it would need it would need to 1. Construct a `List`, 2. Invoke a method call, 3. Iterate over the `List`, 4. Invoke a function for each element.  That said, I wouldn't expect that performance difference to be a concern since we're talking about a fixed (and likely not very large) number of items.